# All wordpress network subfolder sites being redirected to main site

Tags: multisite

I have a WP network setup running the latest versions of WP and Buddypress. I want to set up ~40 users with blogs, and have created these blogs using the Batch Create plugin, but now when I try to visit one of these folders, eg burkphysics.com/elizabethf, it redirects to burkphysics.com. All sites, even sites I create manually do this.

I've followed the config steps to properly configure both my wp-admin file and .htaccess file, and I can't see any problems. This also worked fine last year before I upgraded wordpress and buddypress.

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you installed wordpress in a sub directory called "wordpress" you should try changing your last rewrite rule like this.

```
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, because `/wordpress/` is already set as the `RewriteBase`. My guess is that the problem is at the application level, not the .htaccess level - as in, it's possible that the Batch Create problem didn't create the sites properly, so WP is bailing when you try to load one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the multisite plugin hasnt been deactivated during the wordpress update... It happened to me once and it drove me mad for hours :P